# How to properly regularize a np.polyval() function?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm attempting to recreate and plot this regularization function
[image: this regularization function]
based off of Bishop's Pattern Recognition and ML book, but I am getting vastly different results.

I am using `np.polyfit()` to obtain the coefficients *w* and `np.polyval()` to calculate them with an input.  I get a correctly fit model (though I'm aware of the overfitting problem) when lambda=0 (meaning no regularization has actually taken place), but I struggle to get anything even resembling the examples in the book when lambda is anything else.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code

```
def poly_fit(M,x,t):
    poly = np.polyfit(x, t, deg=M)
    return poly

poly = poly_fit(M,x,t)
reg = np.polyval(poly,rand_gen) + ((lamb/2)*(poly@poly))
```

where `rand_gen` is a vector with random variables, and in my three attempts I set lambda as `lamb=np.exp(-np.inf)`, `lamb=np.exp(-18)`, and `lamb=np.exp(0)`

This is what I'm attempting to recreate:
[image]

This is what I get:

*ln(lambda)=-infinity*:

[image]

*ln(lambda)=-18*:

[image]

*ln(lambda)=0*:

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete; there's enough information to recreate your fits or graphs.  But I wonder, what `t` are you using - the `deg` of the docs?  Looks like the desired fits have a small `deg`, where as the many hump plot is a high degree (9?)

Comment: x= uniform(0,1) with a length of 10.  And t I'm using is t = (2*sin*x)+ gaussian noise.  The desired fits are all of the degree M=9

Comment: The docs for `np.polyfit` say it takes `x, y, deg` as arguments.  That doesn't look like your `(9,x,t)

Comment: I made a poly_fit() function which calls np.polyfit().  Sorry for adding the extra confusion, but I made that because I wanted to have access to the coefficients so I can calculate the RMSE.

I have updated the original post to show this, and added the explanation provided with the image of the desired plots

Comment: In your last plot (ln(lambda)=0) the sine curve is flat while the y-axis is well in the 0 to 1 range, so it seems the sine curve is not the reference. Even if your code is large, you may want to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows where you are stuck to support others to provide you an answer.